# Unity Failed running python.exe when building webgl

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine, emscripten, unity-webgl

I'm trying to build a unity3d project, however when I do I get an error and cannot figure out where the error actually is, it started around the same time I introduced the newsoft and restsharp dll's, though the error remained after I removed those two packages.

The entire message looks as following:

```
Exception: Failed building WebGL Player.
UnityEditor.WebGL.ProgramUtils.StartProgramChecked (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo p) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/ProgramUtils.cs:48)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.EmscriptenLink (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, System.Boolean wasmBuild, System.String sourceFiles, System.String sourceFilesHash) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:425)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.LinkBuild (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:474)
UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/WebGL/Extensions/Unity.WebGL.extensions/BuildPostprocessor.cs:937)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:27)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:287)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc" @"A:\code\Workspaces\unity3d_project\verifi3d\Assets\..\Temp\emcc_arguments.resp"

stdout:
stderr:WARNING:root:--separate-asm works best when compiling to HTML. Otherwise, you must yourself load the '.asm.js' file that is emitted separately, and must do so before loading the main '.js' file. [-Wseparate-asm]warning: unexpected number of arguments 2 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 4 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 2 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 4 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 5 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 4 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 2 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0warning: unexpected number of arguments 3 in call to '_ZN6il2cpp6icalls8mscorlib6System6String22RedirectToCreateStringEv', should be 0error: unresolved symbol: SendRoomDataJSONAborting compilation due to previous errors | undefinedTraceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc", line 10, in <module>    python_selector.run(__file__, profile=True)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\python_selector.py", line 43, in run    sys.exit(run_by_import(filename, main) if on_allowed_version() else run_by_subprocess(filename))  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\python_selector.py", line 13, in run_by_import    return getattr(importlib.import_module(os.path.basename(filename)), main)()  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py", line 1611, in run    final = shared.Building.emscripten(final, append_ext=False, extra_args=extra_args)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 2009, in emscripten    call_emscripten(cmdline)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2340, in _main    temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: main(  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\tempfiles.py", line 93, in run_and_clean    return func()  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2345, in <lambda>    DEBUG=DEBUG,  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 2251, in main    temp_files=temp_files, DEBUG=DEBUG)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 99, in emscript    glue, forwarded_data = compiler_glue(metadata, settings, libraries, compiler_engine, temp_files, DEBUG)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 226, in compiler_glue    glue, forwarded_data = compile_settings(compiler_engine, settings, libraries, temp_files)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 532, in compile_settings    cwd=path_from_root('src'), error_limit=300)  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\jsrun.py", line 132, in run_js    raise Exception('Expected the command ' + str(command) + ' to finish with return code ' + str(assert_returncode) + ', but it returned with code ' + str(proc.returncode) + ' instead! Output: ' + str(ret)[:error_limit])Exception: Expected the command ['C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe', '--stack_size=8192', '--max-old-space-size=4096', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\compiler.js', 'C:\\Users\\thijser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpftpsvx.txt', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Audio.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Cursor.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Eval.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\FileSystem.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Logging.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Profiler.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\SystemInfo.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\UnetWebSocket.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Video.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebCam.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebGL.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebRequest.js', 'A:\\code\\Workspaces\\unity3d_project\\verifi3d\\Assets\\Plugins\\webCommunication.jslib', 'A:\\code\\Workspaces\\unity3d_project\\verifi3d\\Assets\\Plugins\\jsCommunication.jslib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\library_pthread_stub.js'] to finish with return code 0, but it returned with code 1 instead! Output: // The Module object: Our interface to the outside world. We import// and export values on it. There are various ways Module can be used:// 1. Not defined. We create it here// 2. A function parameter, function(Module) { ..generated code.. }// 3. pre-run appended it, var Module = {}; ..generated 
0x00000001415381D8 (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x000000014153E716 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x000000014140D4EB (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00000001408B1580 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00000001418DD198 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000000046FCB630 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000000046FCB503 (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:10] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 
0x0000000046FCAD85 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:48] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 
0x0000000046FCAA19 (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:117] UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object) 
0x000000004602D0FB (Mono JIT Code) [ProgramUtils.cs:48] UnityEditor.WebGL.ProgramUtils:StartProgramChecked (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo) 
0x000000004602645B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPostprocessor.cs:425] UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor:EmscriptenLink (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,bool,string,string) 
0x0000000045F5F86B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPostprocessor.cs:475] UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor:LinkBuild (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs) 
0x00000000193947D3 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPostprocessor.cs:939] UnityEditor.WebGL.WebGlBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs) 
0x0000000019392D81 (Mono JIT Code) [DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:31] UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&) 
0x000000001939206F (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:288] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) 
0x0000000019392510 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFA769CA65B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA76951B72 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2915] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA7695AB5F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2962] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x0000000140C0734A (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x0000000140BFF710 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x0000000140D819EF (Unity) CallMono
0x0000000140D8D1ED (Unity) PostprocessPlayer
0x0000000140D84E89 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild
0x0000000140D845BC (Unity) DoBuildPlayer
0x0000000140D76D55 (Unity) BuildPlayer
0x0000000142291FDA (Unity) BuildPipeline::BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00000001422900EC (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck
0x00000000006DEBA3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,bool)
0x00000000006DDFEB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:170] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 
0x00000000006D647B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 
0x0000000045D563B3 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:892] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform) 
0x0000000045D4C63B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:818] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings () 
0x0000000045D26EBB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:415] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI () 
0x0000000045F67D30 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFA769CA65B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA76951B72 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2915] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA7695AD32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3067] mono_runtime_invoke_checked 
0x00007FFA7695B4C9 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5253] mono_runtime_try_invoke_array 
0x00007FFA7695ACC6 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5131] mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked 
0x00007FFA768FFDC4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [icall.c:3357] ves_icall_InternalInvoke 
0x000000003ECEA6A6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
0x000000003ECFFA5B (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0x000000003ECFF71F (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])
0x000000003EDBB8B3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:295] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string,object) 
0x000000003EDBB703 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:289] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string) 
0x0000000045D24EA3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:105] UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI () 
0x000000004123AFC4 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:216] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,bool) 
0x00000000412395F3 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:378] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 
0x000000003EDB26EB (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:355] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase) 
0x000000003EDA5384 (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:265] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel) 
0x00000000411EB4CB (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:244] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 
0x00000000411EAA2B (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:74] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x00000000411EA394 (Mono JIT Code) [GUIUtility.cs:171] UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x00000000411EA5B3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool_int_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFA769CA65B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA76951B72 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2915] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA7695AB5F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2962] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x0000000140C0734A (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x0000000140BFF710 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x0000000140BFA7CA (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<bool>
0x00000001404182F9 (Unity) IMGUIScriptingClasses::ProcessEvent
0x0000000141399634 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00000001415D0242 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00000001413995BC (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00000001415D159A (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x00000001415CACCD (Unity) GUIView::GUIViewWndProc
0x00007FFACDF86CC1 (USER32) CallWindowProcW
0x00007FFACDF86693 (USER32) DispatchMessageW
0x00000001415EA0A4 (Unity) MainMessageLoop
0x00000001415EC2C8 (Unity) WinMain
0x000000014243127A (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh
0x00007FFACFBB3034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFAD0A01461 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart

Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded'
0x00000001415381D8 (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack
0x000000014153E716 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack
0x000000014140D4EB (Unity) GetStacktrace
0x00000001408B1580 (Unity) DebugStringToFile
0x00000001418DD198 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log
0x0000000046FCB630 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object)
0x0000000046FCB503 (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:10] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[]) 
0x0000000046FCAD85 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:48] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object) 
0x000000004C616F1C (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:98] UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object) 
0x00000000006DE523 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions) 
0x00000000006D647B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions) 
0x0000000045D563B3 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:892] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform) 
0x0000000045D4C63B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:818] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings () 
0x0000000045D26EBB (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:415] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI () 
0x0000000045F67D30 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFA769CA65B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA76951B72 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2915] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA7695AD32 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:3067] mono_runtime_invoke_checked 
0x00007FFA7695B4C9 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5253] mono_runtime_try_invoke_array 
0x00007FFA7695ACC6 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:5131] mono_runtime_invoke_array_checked 
0x00007FFA768FFDC4 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [icall.c:3357] ves_icall_InternalInvoke 
0x000000003ECEA6A6 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
0x000000003ECFFA5B (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
0x000000003ECFF71F (Mono JIT Code) System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke (object,object[])
0x000000003EDBB8B3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:295] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string,object) 
0x000000003EDBB703 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:289] UnityEditor.HostView:Invoke (string) 
0x0000000045D24EA3 (Mono JIT Code) [HostView.cs:105] UnityEditor.HostView:OldOnGUI () 
0x000000004123AFC4 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:216] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,bool) 
0x00000000412395F3 (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:378] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event) 
0x000000003EDB26EB (Mono JIT Code) [IMGUIContainer.cs:355] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase) 
0x000000003EDA5384 (Mono JIT Code) [EventDispatcher.cs:265] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventDispatcher:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IPanel) 
0x00000000411EB4CB (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:244] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel) 
0x00000000411EAA2B (Mono JIT Code) [UIElementsUtility.cs:74] UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x00000000411EA394 (Mono JIT Code) [GUIUtility.cs:171] UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr) 
0x00000000411EA5B3 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_bool_int_intptr (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
0x00007FFA769CA65B (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [mini-runtime.c:2809] mono_jit_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA76951B72 (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2915] do_runtime_invoke 
0x00007FFA7695AB5F (mono-2.0-bdwgc) [object.c:2962] mono_runtime_invoke 
0x0000000140C0734A (Unity) scripting_method_invoke
0x0000000140BFF710 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke
0x0000000140BFA7CA (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke<bool>
0x00000001404182F9 (Unity) IMGUIScriptingClasses::ProcessEvent
0x0000000141399634 (Unity) GUIView::ProcessRetainedMode
0x00000001415D0242 (Unity) GUIView::OnInputEvent
0x00000001413995BC (Unity) GUIView::ProcessInputEvent
0x00000001415D159A (Unity) GUIView::ProcessEventMessages
0x000000
```

By the end unity tells me the build succeeded but changes in the editor do not actually prograde to the editor itself (I changed the text in a button and it remains the same). This suggests that the build failed even if the message tells me that the build completed with the result of "success".

I also think the jslib file might be involved in this

```
var WebInteraction =  {
  $TestScript: {
    unityTestVariable:"test_var_declared";
  },
  GetUnityTestVariable: function () {
    return TestScript.unityTestVariable;
  },
  Init: function () {
    TestScript.unityTestVariable = "test_var_initiated";
    console.log("initiated");
  },

  AlertTest: function () {

  },

  ConsoleTest: function (consoleTestText) {
    console.log(Pointer_stringify(consoleTestText));
  },

  CreateScreenShotImageTest: function(){
    console.log("taking screenshot, lol");
  },

  VariableChangeTest: function(json){
        json=Pointer_stringify(json);
      __VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.store.state.unityObject=json;
s
  },
  ProvideCallback: function(obj)
  {
    console.log("ProvideCallback");
    console.log(obj);
    TestScript.callback = obj;
    Runtime.dynCall('v', obj, 0);
  }
};
autoAddDeps(WebInteraction, '$TestScript');
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, WebInteraction);
```

Anybody got any idea what file I should look at for the error?

Comment: This is a pretty old question  Anyway, I will write a possible solution here if someone will face this issue in the future. This error comes when you have a wrong DLLImport. If it fails to map two functions it will not compile.

Comment: @phantasm I'm still around though the problem has long since gone of my radar. If you post a reasonable answer I will accept it.